Is it possibile to make a "baby" version of java (for students)?
I would like to create a custom subset (library?) of the java language and libraries so that my students are restricted to using this custom subset in their assignments.  I know that Dr. Java (a long time ago) accomplished something like this, but that was part of an IDE, whereas I'm hoping I could, say, have a student load the subset in Eclipse (definitely) or other IDEs (possibly) in such a way that using any other parts of Java would require an import.  Is this possible?

You could just use an IDE which would support, say, Java 5 SDK, which is a subset of the much larger Java 17 language spec.

What do you need to remove that is not already behind an import? Unless you meant "import a whole library in the IDE".

Maybe [tag:bluej]

You may use the module system and limit the API to, e.g. java.base. When you use a class path instead, you can add your own access rules in Eclipse.

Voting to re-open. This Question is clear and specific: How to restrict students to a subset of Java features.

It would be possible to use an agent that prevents accessing certain classes/APIs at runtime (see the appendix of JEP 486) and a type filter (or forbidden references as stated earlier) in Eclipse to hide many types from autocomplete.

In terms of built-in functionality in the Java platform itself, this became slightly less impossible in Java 9 when the standard library was broken into many smaller modules, allowing one to create a smaller runtime environment with only specific modules. (See jlink.)
Unfortunately, the fundamental module that all Java programs require, java.base, is still quite large and contains a lot of functionality that a teacher may want to restrict. (See the JavaDoc for a list of all packages it includes.)
However, for more complex things like "write code to parse this XML", it would allow one to slice away the built-in XML parsing module from the runtime.
